# Cannot mount possibly corrupted hard drive?

Tags: macos, external-hard-drive, disk-utility

I have a 1TB external hard drive that I'm trying to get working again so I don't have to buy another.

It was previously encrypted and partitioned. I attempted to remove the partitions (to 1 partition) using disk utility, but now it seems the disk cannot be mounted.

What's the best way to wipe it out and start fresh?

Should I do something like this `dd if=myImage.dd of=/dev/diskN` to put some working disk image on the drive?

When I try to erase the disk on the command line it doesn't work:

```
diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ Grace disk2
Started erase on disk2
Unmounting disk
Creating the partition map
Waiting for partitions to activate
Formatting disk2s2 as Mac OS Extended (Journaled) with name Grace
[ / 0%..10%..20%..30%..40%..50%.......................... ]
[ \ 0%..10%..20%..30%..40%..50%.......................... ]
[ - 0%..10%..20%..30%..40%..50%.......................... ]
newfs_hfs:
WriteBuffer:  pwrite(3, 0x100c68000, 1048576, 3089219584): Resource busy
newfs_hfs: write (sector 6033632): Invalid argument
Mounting disk
Could not mount disk2s2 after erase
Error: -69832: File system formatter failed
```

Anyone have other ideas?

Comment: How do you know the drive is any good? You should download a utility to test it. Depends on your brand of drive. But most manufacturers have some kind of test tool.

Comment: @Appleoddity I did download the WD drive tools but they cant mount it either. I think the drive is good cuz it was working a week ago well.

Answer (score -2):

In this type of situation I like to remove the HDD from the external casing if at all possible (USB Enclosure) and use a SATA cable / power to connect.

That is not always possible, but it removes a potentially faulty USB to SATA adapter.

Secondly I have had good luck with Parted Magic's secure erase options, however since you are already in a Linux distro you can try:

> hdparm -I /dev/X

(Where X matches your device e.g. sda)
This will show if the drive is in a frozen state.

If it is you need to put the machine to sleep and re-awaken or if you are feeling luck hot unplug / replugin a SATA device.

Set a user password: (e.g. Eins)

> hdparm --user-master u --security-set-pass Eins /dev/X

To confirm it worked:

> hdparm -I /dev/X

And finally to erase:

> time hdparm --user-master u --security-erase Eins /dev/X

To confirm:

> hdparm -I /dev/X

Should give you a

> not enabled

Shamelessly scraped from:
https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase

Comment: When did OP say he was in a Linux distro? Everything OP said looks like macOS to me.